# htaccess 301 redirect DIrectory show file on file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I help how setting my htaccess if i want
redirect if youser visit directory

**example.com/data/** need redirect on example.com/404

if user visit file
**example.com/data/myfile.pdf**  show the file or download

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule inside **`/data/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteRule ^/?$ /404 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

that my final configuration and work great

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

ErrorDocument 403 /error/403

DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```